# Convert java.time.temporal.Temporal to java.util.Date

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

How can I convert an `java.time.temporal.Temporal` instance to an `java.util.Date` instance?

```
java.time.temporal.Temporal someTemporal = Instant.now();
java.util.Date some Temporal = x(someTemporal);
```

I have taken a look at [Oracle's legacy time trail documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/legacy.html), but couldn't find a solution that fits.

Comment: The type `Temporal` is so general and abstract that it is nigh to impossible to find a solution i.e. conversion to `java.util.Date`. Consider for example the type `LocalDate`. How can you convert it without any contextual information like time zone or clock time?

Comment: However, if you just want to convert `java.time.Instant` then it is pretty simple. Look at the API of `java.util.Date`. (see method `from(Instant)`).

Answer (score 11):

I strongly suggest to leave out any reference to the (too) general interface `java.time.temporal.Temporal` and just do this:

```
java.util.Date some = java.util.Date.from(Instant.now());
```

Using the interface `Temporal` is almost like using `java.lang.Object`. You should be as concrete as possible (especially in context of date and time). Even the JSR-310-API [officially outputs a warning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html):

> This interface is a framework-level interface that should not be
>   widely used in application code. Instead, applications should create
>   and pass around instances of concrete types, such as LocalDate. There
>   are many reasons for this, part of which is that implementations of
>   this interface may be in calendar systems other than ISO. See
>   ChronoLocalDate for a fuller discussion of the issues.

Answer (score -2):

At the bottom it has:

> Although the java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter provides a powerful mechanism for formatting date and time values, you can also use the java.time temporal-based classes directly with java.util.Formatter and String.format, using the same pattern-based formatting that you use with the java.util date and time classes.

It looks like you may want to use the DateTimeFormatter class, with [documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and maybe going by something like this example:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
String text = date.format(formatter);
LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);
```

Comment: @MenoHochschild right, and my answer provides him with a LocalDate, which is a Date format and can be converted to a java.util.Date object.

Comment: @TrevorYokum The question is asking about converting into a java.util.Date. Your answer has nothing to do with that...

Answer (score -4):

I think you've asked this question slightly wrong. Rather, I believe you want How do I convert any java.time concrete class, e.g. Instant, LocalDate, into a Date using a generic interface. `TemporalAccessor` I believe is that interface.

```
@Test
public void convertTemportalAccessorTypeToDate() throws Exception {
    Instant instant = Instant.now();
    Date expected = Date.from( instant );
    TemporalAccessor now = instant;

    long nanos = now.getLong( ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND );
    long epochSeconds = now.getLong( ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS );
    Date date1 = Date.from( Instant.ofEpochSecond( epochSeconds, nanos ) );
    assertThat( date1, is( expected ));
}
```

that said, the concrete type actually has to support the `ChronoField`, and seems to throw `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException` if it does not, so maybe wrap in a try catch.